# how to use OR array inside AND prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

ièm trying to use OR inside AND by passing an array of object to OR

```
city=[{city:berlin},{city:newyork}]
brand=[{brand:bmw},{brand:nissan}]
  filter: async(_,{city ,brand,model}) =>{
  const ads =await Client.Ads.findMany({where:{
      AND:[
        OR:city
      ,
      OR:brand
      ]
        
      
  }})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this schema file:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model test {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

You can nest AND and OR operators like this:

```js
  await prisma.test.findMany({
    where: {
      AND: [
        {
          OR: [
            {
              name: 'test1',
            },
            {
              name: 'test2',
            },
          ],
        },
        {},
      ],
    },
  });
```

By default all the fields in the where clause are combined with AND operator so you might only need to use the OR operator.

For reference: [AND](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#and) and [OR](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#or) Prisma Documentation.